# State Machine persistence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

How does the persistence work for state machines? More specifically, I would like to know how triggers are persisted.

I would like to understand if it is possible to put long running logic into triggers' actions, or if I should create a "transitional" state with that logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistence for state machines is no different than for other workflows. Whenever the workflow is idle it's state can be persisted. If you are using bookmarks in you workflow, either yourself or indirectly through a Receive activity, they will be persisted as part of your workflow state.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, your help with WF is always priceless.
Does it mean that wherever we are (trigger action, state entry, state exit) the current point can be persisted (with bookmark, receive or explicit persist)?

Comment: The workflow can only be persisted if it is idle. So there is no code actually executing in the workflow. basically it is waiting for a bookmark to be resumed. And bookmarks are part of the workflow data that is persisted, in fact that is what they are designed for.